# How to run x64 Debug Mode DLLs are "Any CPU"?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, dll, platform-independent

I compiled DLLs to be "Any CPU" so they can be run in both x86 and x64, but when I try to run in Debug Mode (x64) it keeps telling me Error while trying to run project: Could not load file or assembly 'Project' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

However, when I run the *.exe that I create from the Debug directory or run it in Visual Studio without Debugging, it runs fine, it also works if I run it in x86 Debug Mode. Why would it work in everything but Debug Mode in Visual Studio?

The application is a desktop application, so there is no IIS Application Pool to change to 32-bit.

Comment: What is the Platform for 'Project' set to?

Comment: @Gray Platform is set to x64

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that sometimes when you change configurations, it doesn't change all of the projects. If you go to Build > Configuration Manager in the x64 config, are all of the projects set to build x64 versions?

Comment: Yup, everything set to x64.

Answer (score 0):

use [corflags.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164699%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to get the PE info for your 'project' dll. It should say `PE:PE32+` and `32Bit:0` if it was built as x64. Check to make sure the caller of 'Project' is referencing the project, and not a rogue dll in a build directory elsewhere.

- check references first
- use corflags to check that reference
- report findings

Comment: What should that tell me? The only time the Solution doesn't run is in Debug Mode for x64. It runs in Release, runs without Debugging, and runs if I run the exe.

Comment: You could be referencing a dll in visual studio that is not copied locally. Once that is confirmed, you can check to see what the dll in the debug folder is being built as. It might provide some insight into why you would be getting a bad image format. It is hard to debug these things when you don't know what the environment is like, so I was just trying to eliminate some variables. If you would rather not check that, then that is fine too. Good luck.

Comment: Does corflags work on exes? Because `Project` is the startup project so it is an exe.

Comment: Haha, dude... that literally takes like 3 seconds to check (it does). I feel like you don't want to try the stuff I am suggesting. Like I said before, that is fine. I am sure you will figure something out.